# Photons having mass, in light of Stueckelberg's QED, and dark energy

Tags: photons, quantum-electrodynamics, dark-energy

I know this may count as a duplicate but was wondering in light of Stueckelberg's renormalisation of QED with a mass term for the photon. The question is, if this is the case, could ordinary photons be a potential candidate to explain dark energy?

Comment: To reopen this post (v1), consider to only ask one subquestion per post.